# iPhone - pdf encryption

Tags: iphone, pdf, encryption, ios4

I've been searching the internet for most of the day today trying to find an answer to this problem. Bascially, I'm trying to create a small app which receives pdfs (from the iTunes file explorer and from a url) then encrypts them and saves them for decryption later.

I've tried using Quartz but with not a lot of documentation available, its difficult. I'm just looking for some guidance on how i should approach this. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You want to encrypt them? or just save them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Im using this: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [PDFDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class in Quartz2D to read PDF data from a file or a URL. Once read, you can then save the document with optional encryption via the property *kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword*.

Reading:

```
PDFDocument * pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData: data];
//or
PDFDocument * pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL: url];
```

Writing, encrypted:

```
NSDictionary * pdfOpts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, @"mypassword", nil];
[pdfDoc writeToFile: somepath withOptions: pdfOpts];
```

You can get a complete list of the specifiable options from the [CGPDFContext Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000957) on Apple's developer web site.

Comment: +1 Good answer, thanks, but i already found a solution which works well.